# Bootstrap-Select and keyboard navigation

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I am using bootstrap-select https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

and I  have a the following dropdown with image URLS as the value.

Everything works fine when I am using my mouse and selecting each option. However, when I use the up and down arrows of my keyboard and highlight each option I would like an event to fire so that I can flip though the available image previews. (Not shown here) When  I use the mouse to click on the highlighted option it displays a preview of the image selected as expected.

The questions is how can I implement it so that the as the user is moving up and down with the keyboard arrows the value is selected so they can easily flip thought the available images without hitting enter each time.  I have tried the following

```
$('.selectpicker').on('changed.bs.select', function (e, clickedIndex, newValue, oldValue) {
    var selected = $(e.currentTarget).val();
    alert(selected);
});
 but this only works after I hit enter. Any suggestions. 


    <select class="selectpicker form-control" data-size="10" name="cboImage" id="cboImage" onchange="cboImage_onChange()" size="1" tabindex="-98">

    <option value="images/1x1.gif">[BLANK IMAGE]</option>
    <option value="upload/33/img_3009.jpg">10-16-2015 11-56-30 AM.jpg</option>
    <option value="upload/00/img_3031.jpg">10478631_1494051514186448_2207392604969581462_o.jpg</option>
    <option value="upload/BB/img_3003.jpg" selected="">10920935_1385769295058553_7186298008992739460_n.jpg</option>
    <option value="upload/22/img_3006.jpg">11-29-2014 6-35-20 PM.jpg</option>
    <option value="upload/22/img_3004.jpg">11025665_1380482578935990_5955532852167626303_n.jpg</option>
    <option value="upload/77/img_2913.jpg">12339668_1517870915178926_9132688390289736139_o.jpg</option>
    <option value="upload/EE/img_2972.jpg">269586_10151304206069257_1562006627_n.png</option>
    <option value="upload/88/img_3005.jpg">3305476.jpg</option>

<option value="upload/00/img_3008.jpg">536962_1.jpg</option>
<option value="upload/FF/img_2969.jpg">9-3-2015 9-03-19 AM.jpg</option>
<option value="upload/77/img_2971.jpg">analyze_image.jpg</option>
<option value="upload/AA/img_3007.jpg">Copy of FL-SAR00_226876_1.jpg</option>
<option value="upload/11/img_2914.jpg">holiday2015_1_image.jpg</option>
<option value="upload/33/img_3015.jpg">IMAG0002.jpg</option>
<option value="upload/BB/img_3013.jpg">IMAG0002.jpg</option>
<option value="upload/55/img_3014.jpg">IMAG0003.jpg</option>
<option value="upload/BB/img_3016.jpg">IMAG0003.jpg</option>
<option value="upload/66/img_3017.jpg">IMAG0004.jpg</option>
<option value="upload/CC/img_3012.jpg">IMAG0004.jpg</option>
<option value="upload/66/img_3019.jpg">IMAG0023.jpg</option>
<option value="upload/FF/img_3018.jpg">IMAG0053.jpg</option>
<option value="upload/88/img_3011.jpg">image119037-180ae8ff18269a6e395200cb831d928e.jpg</option>
<option value="upload/66/img_3029.jpg">IMG_1113.JPG</option>
<option value="upload/CC/img_3028.jpg">IMG_1114.JPG</option>
<option value="upload/FF/img_3027.jpg">IMG_1123.JPG</option>
<option value="upload/BB/img_3030.jpg">IMG_1125.JPG</option>
<option value="upload/AA/img_2917.jpg">L7ViI0Pm_400x400.png</option>
<option value="upload/CC/img_3025.jpg">MuscleMadison11yrs.jpg</option>
<option value="upload/FF/img_2960.jpg">My Image</option>
<option value="upload/BB/img_3026.jpg">TimesSquare2013.jpg</option>
<option value="upload/99/img_3010.jpg">Windsor-at-Lakoya-Front-Elevation-1024x656.jpg</option>

            </select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use the key UP/DOWN to select the elements you need to attach a handler to keydown event for the $('div.dropdown-menu.open li').

To select the element you need to use:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', selVal);
```

So the snippet is:

```js
$(function () {
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    style: 'btn-info',
    size: 4
  });
  $('div.dropdown-menu.open li').on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { // Up
      var previousEle = $(this).prev();
      if (previousEle.length == 0) {
        previousEle = $(this).nextAll().last();
      }
      var selVal = $('.selectpicker option').filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() == previousEle.text();
      }).val();
      $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', selVal);

      return;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { // Down
      var nextEle = $(this).next();
      if (nextEle.length == 0) {
        nextEle = $(this).prevAll().last();
      }
      var selVal = $('.selectpicker option').filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() == nextEle.text();
      }).val();
      $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', selVal);

      return;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.18/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.18/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker form-control" data-size="10" name="cboImage" id="cboImage" size="1" tabindex="-98">
    <option value="images/1x1.gif">[BLANK IMAGE]</option>
    <option value="upload/33/img_3009.jpg">10-16-2015 11-56-30 AM.jpg</option>
    <option value="upload/00/img_3031.jpg">10478631_1494051514186448_2207392604969581462_o.jpg</option>
    <option value="upload/BB/img_3003.jpg" selected="">10920935_1385769295058553_7186298008992739460_n.jpg</option>
    <option value="upload/22/img_3006.jpg">11-29-2014 6-35-20 PM.jpg</option>
    <option value="upload/22/img_3004.jpg">11025665_1380482578935990_5955532852167626303_n.jpg</option>
    <option value="upload/77/img_2913.jpg">12339668_1517870915178926_9132688390289736139_o.jpg</option>
    <option value="upload/EE/img_2972.jpg">269586_10151304206069257_1562006627_n.png</option>
    <option value="upload/88/img_3005.jpg">3305476.jpg</option>
    <option value="upload/00/img_3008.jpg">536962_1.jpg</option>
    <option value="upload/FF/img_2969.jpg">9-3-2015 9-03-19 AM.jpg</option>
    <option value="upload/77/img_2971.jpg">analyze_image.jpg</option>
    <option value="upload/AA/img_3007.jpg">Copy of FL-SAR00_226876_1.jpg</option>
    <option value="upload/11/img_2914.jpg">holiday2015_1_image.jpg</option>
    <option value="upload/33/img_3015.jpg">IMAG0002.jpg</option>
    <option value="upload/BB/img_3013.jpg">IMAG0002.jpg</option>
    <option value="upload/55/img_3014.jpg">IMAG0003.jpg</option>
    <option value="upload/BB/img_3016.jpg">IMAG0003.jpg</option>
    <option value="upload/66/img_3017.jpg">IMAG0004.jpg</option>
    <option value="upload/CC/img_3012.jpg">IMAG0004.jpg</option>
    <option value="upload/66/img_3019.jpg">IMAG0023.jpg</option>
    <option value="upload/FF/img_3018.jpg">IMAG0053.jpg</option>
    <option value="upload/88/img_3011.jpg">image119037-180ae8ff18269a6e395200cb831d928e.jpg</option>
    <option value="upload/66/img_3029.jpg">IMG_1113.JPG</option>
    <option value="upload/CC/img_3028.jpg">IMG_1114.JPG</option>
    <option value="upload/FF/img_3027.jpg">IMG_1123.JPG</option>
    <option value="upload/BB/img_3030.jpg">IMG_1125.JPG</option>
    <option value="upload/AA/img_2917.jpg">L7ViI0Pm_400x400.png</option>
    <option value="upload/CC/img_3025.jpg">MuscleMadison11yrs.jpg</option>
    <option value="upload/FF/img_2960.jpg">My Image</option>
    <option value="upload/BB/img_3026.jpg">TimesSquare2013.jpg</option>
    <option value="upload/99/img_3010.jpg">Windsor-at-Lakoya-Front-Elevation-1024x656.jpg</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great solution. It worked great for what I was trying to do.

Comment: Is this working in 2021? I am getting the error Uncaught TypeError: we.getInstance(...) is null

Comment: @gaetanoM, This answer is 5 years old.  I haven't change anything, Just copy the whole code and added the latest plugin and I got error in console Uncaught TypeError: we.getInstance(...) is null

Comment: @user9437856 Snippet updated with the last version of "bootstrap-select". You can see by yourself it works fine. So, where is your error? I'm sure you have an issue in another part of your code. Please, create a snippet (i.e.: https://jsfiddle.net/) and let me take a look.  Thanks.